# Counting the number of digits in a concatenation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Concatenate the numbers $2^{1971}$ and $5^{1971}$. How many digits are there in the new number? How do I count them?

Comment: You mean total number of digits in the two numbers? What do you mean by new number?

Comment: Example: For $2^3, 5^3$ the new numberis $8125$ so the new number($8125$) has $4$ digits.

Comment: So you want the sum of digits of the two numbers.

Comment: Actually, I believe he wants the number of digits, not the sum.

Comment: the sum of number of digits

Comment: @cirpis That's the same thing. The sum of a number is the number.

Comment: He wants the number of digits in the new number, which is the sum of the numbers of digits in the two separate numbers which are being concatenated.

Comment: I edited the post to improve the meaning. Others can give it a try if you'd like something better.

Comment: @mweiss yeah thanks, I was confused by how badly the original question was asked.

Comment: @bigli I note you took an interesting example in that  $2^3, 5^3 = 3^4, 5^2   $

Answer (score 9):

let $$10^m<2^{1971}<10^{m+1}$$ and
$$10^n<5^{1971}<10^{n+1}$$
This inequality is true since every number that is not a power of ten is between two consecutive powers of ten.
Now let us multiply both inequalities
$$10^m*10^n=10^{n+m}<2^{1971}*5^{1971}=10^{1971}<10^{m+1}*10^{n+1}=10^{n+m+2}$$
thus
$$m+n<1971<m+n+2$$
the only whole number between $m+n$ and $m+n+2$ is $m+n+1$,thus
$$m+n+1=1971$$
$$m+n=1970$$
and since $m+1$ and $n+1$ are the number of digits of $2^{1971}$ and $5^{1971}$ respectiveley,then their sum is equal to the number of digits of the new number. Your new number will have $$m+n+2=1972$$ digits.

Comment: Why $2^{1971}\times5^{1971}$?????

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks mate! corrected.

Comment: @bigli: Because it works!  Check out the neat argument showing why.

Comment: maybe it's worth pointing out that this worked out cleverly because the bases were 2 and 5 and the exponents were the same, so that multiplying gives a power of ten? in general, you'd have to find $m$ and $n$ separately.

Comment: More generally, this should apply to any factorization of a power of 10.

Comment: @cirpis: Please describe why $2^{1971}\times5^{1971}$.

Comment: @bigli: The multiplication is just a device for putting $m$ and $n$ together. cirpis could equivalently have written $m < \log_{10}(2^{1971}) < m+1$ and add (rather than multiply) this to the similar equation for $n$. It's the same math.

Comment: @bigli as symplectomorphic pointed out, this gives us a base ten number, which we can compare to the lower and higher bound numbers, which are both base ten numbers

Comment: @bigli: cirpus did that because (s)he multiplied the two inequalities.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I really like this answer.  Nice and slick.

Answer (score 2):

This is only one way and probably will not be "nicest" way, but we can get the number of digits of a number if we just take log$_{10}|x|$ and then round up.

So for $2^{1971}$ we have

$$
\text{number of digits } = \lceil 1971 \text{log}_{10} (2) \rceil = 594
$$

Comment: I'd just like to point out that this works for $x\geq1$ and $x\leq-1$ as it's undefined at 0.